# How to remove part name from both ToC and document?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, babel, parts

I am writing a major report in Norwegian. I need to remove the fixed name - and numbering of the document's parts. The MWE shows where I am at.
The MWE produces a good ToC, but the parts page retains an error - a . above the  part name.

Using \part*{} is not an option as it removes the entry from ToC, and using an \addcontentsline{} will result in an incorrect page number being reported in the ToC.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\addto\captionsnorwegian{\renewcommand{\partname}{}}
\setcounter{part}{-\maxdimen}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `norwegian` vs `norsk` (those probably need to match)

Comment: Why not just use `\part*{bla}`?

Comment: @daleif I do not use \part*{} because the page number in the toc gets messed up from that (using \addcontentsline{} to get it into the ToC)

and the example above does yield the desired outcome - but only in the ToC.

Comment: @daleif I tried matching them - no dice I am afraid.

Comment: Could you please explain page numbers in TOC getting messed up?

Comment: Both needs to be called `norsk`

Comment: If both are called norsk the result is a long list of errors. 

The \addcontentsline{} will reference the next page with a part, chapter, section, etc. (or the previous one, if you place it before the \part*{} command) .  As \part{} creates a new page, and cleardoublepage after itself the page number will be off by at least 1.

Comment: I don't get any errors if I use `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}`  and `\captionsnorsk`. And you are still not being any clear in your explanation as to why `\part*` cannot be used? Should the part title be in the toc or not? That is not at all clear from your question. Perhaps you should rephrase your question such that it is easier to understand the end goal.

Comment: Right you are, I must have mistyped it. Sorry. I still get an empty . above the section title. Number and name are gone.

I am sorry if I am not being clear above.

If I have the following code:

\section{a}
some text
\part*{B} \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{B}
\section{b}

what results is that the ToC will reference the page number for section b.
If I write:

\section{a}
some text
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{B}\part*{B} 
\section{b}

the ToC will reference section a.

Comment: Generally you cannot use `\part*{..}` and `\addcontentsline` because of the newpage(s) that `\part` emits. Again please update your question with an exact statement of what exactly the end goal is. Then it is a lot easier to find a solution.

Comment: that was already mentioned in the original question, daleif.
But sure, I can make it more verbose for you. No problem.

Comment: Do not redefine `\partname` to be empty.  If you want to change the content of the part prefix line, you can redefine `\partformat`. But for an unnumbered part with ToC entry use  `\addpart` (provided by the KOMA-Script class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KOMA-Script class `scrbook` provides `\addpart` for an unnumbered part title with ToC entry.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addpart{bla}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a simple solution.